# Jquery - drag and drop into particular area

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

Here my Jquery:

```
    $(".list").draggable({helper: 'clone', cursor: 'hand'});
    $(".drop1").droppable({
        accept: '.list',
        hoverClass: 'dropareahover',
        drop: function(ev, ui){
         var targetId = $(this).attr("id");
         var allTargets = $("#" + targetId, ".tble");
         $("#" + targetId).each(function() {         
            //here i have to write the conditions.                      
            });
        }
 });
```

i need to place the content into particular area. if i place the content other area. it will not accept.

Comment: please be more specific about what your problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for? (the revert option for jquery draggable)

`$(".list" ).draggable({ helper: 'clone', cursor: 'hand', revert: 'invalid'});`

From: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

> If revert set to true, the element will return to its start position
>   when dragging stops. Possible string values: 'valid', 'invalid'. If
>   set to invalid, revert will only occur if the draggable has not been
>   dropped on a droppable. For valid, it's the other way around.
>
> Code examples
>
> Initialize a draggable with the revert option specified.

`$(".selector" ).draggable({ revert: true });`